# R: number of parallel workers decreases during execution of long task with `foreach` with backend `doMC`

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a long running task (about 3-4 hours) and I use the `doMC` backend and a `foreach (...) %dopar%` loop. Code:

```
registerDoMC(4)
res <- foreach(i=1:n, .combine=function(x,y) rbindlist(list(x,y)), .inorder=FALSE, .errorhandling="stop", .verbose=TRUE) %dopar%
{
   # do some stuff with data.table and append row at the end (that's why I use this combine function)
}
```

At some point during my execution, the number of parallel workers reduces: I originally set it to 4, and the number of active workers reduces to 2 when I inspect my processes in `htop`. At the end of my `foreach` I don't get any errors (even with verbose on) so I am completely baffled as to what is happening. Has anyone seen this problem before? (I am running on Linux btw). Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am happy to provide more information if anyone requests.

Comment: Are you sure the processes didn't just go down the list because they had finished the tasks?

Comment: I was actually reading [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578784/parallelizing-heterogenous-tasks-in-r-foreach-domc-doparallel?rq=1](this): so it seems when the first two processes finish their tasks, they just sit iddle. I think that would explain my problem!

Comment: Well, is there even a problem?

Comment: no, I will update my question with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578784/parallelizing-heterogenous-tasks-in-r-foreach-domc-doparallel?noredirect=1&lq=1), `doMC` preschedules tasks by default, which might cause some workers to finish earlier and sit idle. The solution was the same as in that question:

```
opts <- list(preschedule=FALSE)
results <- foreach(i=1:10, .options.multicore=opts) %dopar% {
    # ...
}
```